# Как отключить кэширование в Django?

Tags: django

Делаю информационное табло.

Когда я удаляю или меняю картинку в директории, то почему-то картинка не удаляется при обновлении страницы.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы все менялось сразу?

Внизу предлагаю картинки и код(templets).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)